# Setting heap size for rmiregistry

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I want to set heap size for RMI registry. Is that similar to java or any other format

Comment: rmiregistry -J-Xmx60m 
Is this what you are looking ?

Comment: Yes I'm looking fro this one thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmiregistry -J-Xmx64m

-J Pass argument to the java interpreter